# SQL: Selecting and Excluding Groups by Many IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like the Following:

```
| id | Category |
|----|----------|
| 1  | Red      |
| 1  | Cat      |
| 2  | Blue     |
| 3  | Yellow   |
| 3  | Dog      |
| 3  | Bike     |
| 4  | Blue     |
| 4  | Cat      |
```

What I want is to group by id and keep only those ids which have all three of the following characteristics:

1. At least 1 color (Red, Yellow, Blue)
2. At least 1 animal (Dog, Cat, Fish)
3. NOT any modes of transportation (Bike, Car, Bus)

So in the above table example, I would like to keep and then group by 1 and 4, but exclude 2 and 3.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
GROUP BY id
HAVING(    (sum(case when (code_value IN ('Red', 'Yellow', 'Blue')  then 1 else 0 end) > 0)
           AND
           (sum(case when (code_value IN ('Cat', 'Dog', 'Fish')  then 1 else 0 end) > 0)
           AND
           (sum(case when (code_value IN ('Bike', 'Car', 'Bus') then 0 else 1 end) > 0)
       )
```

This concept seems to work, but is very slow. I'm wondering if anyone else has a better idea for this. Note for this to work, there will be cases where I will have many more than 3 characteristics, so it would be ideal if it was easily expandable.

Comment: Ah, apologies, it's MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You can first calculate ids that have at least one of group 3 members. Then except those ids at first. So something like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
where id NOT IN
(
select id from table where code_value in ('Bike', 'Car', 'Bus') 
)
GROUP BY id
HAVING(    (sum(case when (code_value IN ('Red', 'Yellow', 'Blue'))  then 1 else 0 end)>0  
AND
            sum(case when (code_value IN ('Cat', 'Dog', 'Fish'))  then 1 else 0 end)>0
))
```

Comment: Yes, thank you; similar to Gordon's idea, limiting the data before the GROUP BY command helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Consider storing your selection characteristics in separate lookup tables, *colorsTable, animalsTable, vehiclesTable* (each with distinct *code_value* data), that can expand without limit. Then join them as derived tables (or views) to your main aggregate query:

```
SELECT t.id    
FROM mytable As t
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT s1.id, count(*) As cnt1 
    FROM myTable s1 INNER JOIN colorsTable s2
    ON s1.code_value = s2.code_value
    GROUP BY s1.id) As a
ON t.id = a.id

LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT s1.id, count(*) As cnt2
    FROM myTable s1 INNER JOIN animalsTable s2
    ON s1.code_value = s2.code_value
    GROUP BY s1.id) As b
ON t.id = b.id

LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT s1.id, count(*) As cnt3 
    FROM myTable s1 INNER JOIN vehiclesTable s2  
    ON s1.code_value = s2.code_value     
    GROUP BY s1.id) As c
ON t.id = c.id

WHERE a.cnt1 > 0 AND b.cnt2 > 0 AND c.cnt3 IS NULL
GROUP BY t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not affect performance, but I would write the query as:

```
HAVING sum(code_value IN ('Red', 'Yellow', 'Blue')) > 0 AND
       sum(code_value IN ('Cat', 'Dog', 'Fish')) > 0 AND
       sum(code_value IN ('Bike', 'Car', 'Bus')) = 0
```

Then, if you write the full query as:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE code_value IN ('Red', 'Yellow', 'Blue', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Fish', 'Bike', 'Car', 'Bus')
GROUP BY id
HAVING sum(code_value IN ('Red', 'Yellow', 'Blue')) > 0 AND
       sum(code_value IN ('Cat', 'Dog', 'Fish')) > 0 AND
       sum(code_value IN ('Bike', 'Car', 'Bus')) = 0
```

Then the size of the data before the `GROUP BY` is reduced.  This version can also take advantage of an index on `table(code_value, id)`.  This might help the performance a bit, depending on the distribution of the data.

Comment: Yes, this helps significantly. Thank you.